# MySQL: How to insert multiple records with same ID autoincrement

Tags: mysql, database, auto-increment

I have a table with 1 column that stores the ID auto_increment and with that instruction:

```
$query = "SELECT first_data, second_data, third_data
            FROM table_data
                WHERE condition = 'value_condition'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $valueone = $row['first_data'];
            $valuetwo = $row['second_data'];
            $valuethree = $row['third_data'];

            $queryTwo = "INSERT INTO historial_ventas (reg1, reg2, reg3) 
                        VALUES('$ivalueone','$valuetwo','$valuethree')";
            $resultTwol = mysql_query($queryTwo) or die(mysql_error());
        }
    } else {
        return false;
}
```

Information is stored as follows:

```
ID(auto_increment)  reg1      reg2      reg3
______________________________________________
1                   value1    value2    value3
2                   value1    value2    value3
3                   value1    value2    value3
4                   value1    value2    value3
```

But I want the records maintained in the while loop, stored with the same ID as in a purchase online, ie you save the products and their features but with the same ID to buy, as this way:

```
ID(auto_increment)  reg1      reg2      reg3
______________________________________________
1                   value1    value2    value3
1                   value1    value2    value3
1                   value1    value2    value3
1                   value1    value2    value3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normalized way is to use a joint table like this:

[image: Purchase System]

Both `PurchaseId` and `ItemId` are set to auto-increment. The purpose of a Primary Key is to uniquely identify each row.

### Updated: Customer

Read up on [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) on how you can design your database to be effective.

[image]

Comment: And if I want store the name_of_purchaser, address_of_purchaser and email_of_purchaser, In which table would be stored?

Comment: You can normalize it into a Customer table. Each Customer can has multiple Purchases, and each Purchase can has only one Customer.

Comment: Then, the column foreign key will be PurchaseID(references to table Purchase) and primary key will be IDCustomer?

Comment: But PurchaseItem table, the original question arises, how can I save in the field PurchaseID the same for all the products you buy? if for example: 1 user buy 2 movies, then the Purchase table would look like: PurchaseID: 1, Created: 7/10/2012 .. PurchaseItem table should look like: PurchaseID: 1, Itemid: 01, Quantity: 1; PurchaseID: 1, ItemId: 02, Quantity: 1 ... and Item table would read: ItemId: 01, Name: Tron Legacy, ItemId: 02, Name: Terminator ... and tables should be

Comment: Already done! Thank you for your answers :), I have some normalized databases but yesterday I felt that I did not need to do with this system because it was a project but in the end I had to!

Comment: normalization will help make your system easier to build. you'll have more ease and control at later stage of development.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming the `ID` column is defined as a primary key, in which case its entire purpose is supplying a unique piece of data to identify each record by - it's impossible to have two records in the same table with the same primary key. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? If you want to store the purchase ID, you should create a separate column for it and store it explicitly - an auto increment column isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: I was writing roughly the same answer, but you got it first

Comment: True, I forget that there can't be a same fields when the column is primary key .. then, how should have my tables to store products from  with the same ID?

Comment: Normalization is what you should be going for - check out @mauris's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the auto-increment and manually enter the id number. Also you need to check if it is set to a primary key (ie. unique). Make sure this is what you want to do because removing the uniqueness may cause issues with duplicity later.

To do this before you enter the while loop you can get the maximum number (`select max(id) from tablename`), increment it by one and then insert it within the while loop.

```
$query = "SELECT max(id)
            FROM historial_ventas";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

//increase you resulting number
$result = $result + 1

    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $valueone = $row['first_data'];
            $valuetwo = $row['second_data'];
            $valuethree = $row['third_data'];

            $queryTwo = "INSERT INTO historial_ventas (id, reg1, reg2, reg3) 
                        VALUES('$result', '$ivalueone','$valuetwo','$valuethree')";
            $resultTwol = mysql_query($queryTwo) or die(mysql_error());
        }
    } else {
        return false;
}
```